# How do I reset my entire stack in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, navigation

My app consists of a Stack that looks like this:

1. Home
2. Start
3. Task details
4. End task

When the user presses a TouchableOpacity in the End task screen I want to reset the stack and return to the Home screen. I've tried using

```
navigation.dispatch(StackActions.popToTop());
```

But this isn't working. `navigation` is a variable assigned to `useNavigation()`. Is there a way to return to home using this hook?

Comment: Try using [CommonActions.reset](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-actions#reset)

Answer (score 1):

You can try,

```
import {CommonActions} from '@react-navigation/native';

navigation.dispatch(
          CommonActions.reset({
                index: 0,
                routes: [
                 {
                   name: 'Home'
                 },
                ],
          })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If `Home` is the initial route of the `Stack`, then we can reset the stack to the initial route using the `popToTop` function of the `navigation` object.

Furthermore, we do not need to use the `useNavigation` hook since `EndTask` is a screen located in the stack navigator. It will be passed to the component by the framework.

Here is a code snippet.

```js
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.popToTop()}> ... </TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
props.navigation.reset({ routes: [{ name: "Mainpage" }] });
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.